# Recurrence relation solution for relations with two interdependent variables

Tags: recurrence

I came across the following problem in an online challenge.

Consider the following vectors:

```
x = [3, 4, ...]
y = [2, 3, ...]
```

Such that for i >= 2:

```
x[i] = x[i-1] + 3 * y[i-2]
y[i] = 2 * y[i-1] + 2 * x[i-2]
```

What is x[10^15] ?

While the problem has a very straightforward solution, the problem is the 10^15 value which cannot be calculated in a small time. Only thing I can think of is that we have to derive a polynomial from the recurrence relation - However this isn't easy to do. Am I missing something?

Comment: This: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784710/how-to-prove-fibonacci-sequence-with-matrices can be straightforwardly adapted. To compute n-th power of matrix fast use binary exponentiation: https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/binary-exp.html.

Comment: @dyukha I am not able to form the matrices. If I assume the base as [ [xn, yn-1], [xn-1, yn] ] and the multiplicative as [ [1, 2], [3, 2] ]. The yn-1 and xn-1 are not remaining in a recurrent format after transformation. Can you please tell me the matrices?

Comment: In case of Fibonacci your coordinates are [F[n], F[n-1]], and using matrix [[1 1], [1 0]] you can get it from [F[n-1], F[n-2]]. In this case you coordinates are [x[n], x[n-1], y[n], y[n-1]], so you need a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: @dyukha thank you. Got it. I'll try to post the proper solution if I get time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem statement can be express as matrix multiplication as follows:

```
A= [
    [1, 0, 0, 3],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0]
]

    [xn+1, xn, yn+1, yn] = A*[xn, xn-1, yn, yn-1]
=>  [xn+1, xn, yn+1, yn] = A^(n-1) * [x1, x0, y1, y0]

[x1, x0, y1, y0] = [4, 3, 3, 2]
```

While not mentioned in the problem, since the matrix multiplication exceeds integer limits, the solution needs to be expressed in as remainder of some prime number. Let the prime number be 1000000007. But how can we not exceed the integer limits while multiplying? Consider the following:

```
(X * Y) mod p = ((X mod p) * (Y mod p)) mod p

Now, X = A^n
Let, A^n mod p = B
Now, B = B mod p

So,
(X * Y) mod p = 
    ((X mod p) * (Y mod p)) mod p
=>  ((A^n mod p) * (Y mod p)) mod p
=>  ( B * (Y mod p)) mod p
=>  ((B mod p) * (Y mod p)) mod p
=> (B * Y) mod p
```

So a simple python implementation would be:

```py
import numpy as np

p = 1000000007
A= np.array([
    [1, 0, 0, 3],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0]
])
Y = np.array([4, 3, 3, 2])

# We will use binary exponentiation for fast matrix multiplication
# See: https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/binary-exp.html
# The `power` list is the array of A's powers needed for that
powers = []
powers.append(A % p)
for i in range(1, 50): # Till 50 since 10^15 ~= 2^50
    Ap = powers[i - 1]
    powers.append(Ap.dot(Ap) % p)

def solve(n):
    pow_of_a = n - 3
    index = 0
    prod = np.identity(4)
    while (pow_of_a > 0):
        if (pow_of_a & 1) == 1:
            prod = prod.dot(powers[index])
        pow_of_a >>= 1  
        index += 1
    B = prod % p
    print(B.dot(Y) % p)
```